# Incorrect result for some indicators using TA-Lib

Tags: java, trading, ta-lib

I'm getting shifted "to past" result of some indicators when using TA-Lib.

Here it is **incorrect** shifted results: ( `TEMA` dark blue line is visible by a click/enlarge the picture )
[image]
[**`TEMA`** indicator chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LNuW.png)

Here it is **correct** results from Dukascopy:
[image]
[**`TEMA`** indicator chart from Dukascopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7tvX.png)

My Java source code for calculation indicators:

```
    //initialization
    double[] outRes = new double[array.length];
    MInteger begin = new MInteger();
    MInteger length = new MInteger();

    //library call
    Core c = new Core();
    RetCode retCode = c.tema(0, array.length - 1, array, period, begin, length, outRes);

    //result handling
    if (retCode == RetCode.Success) {
        return outRes;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error in TEMA calculation");
        return null;
    }
```

Looks like bug in TA-Lib.

Does anybody encountered this problem? I heard before that there are forks of TA-Lib. Can anybody advise such forks or any other solution?

Comment: At it's a shift would be great to see how you match your input periods with output results.

Comment: To clarify the issue, I prepared the example with high-price extremum and 5-period TEMA. [link](http://i.piccy.info/i9/7fbd00d2062558612e6546a488d17ee8/1466253286/36639/1044288/chart.png) As you can see, high-price on this chart is 1.3298.

My input array with close prices is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/QSvs5KxZ)

And calculated array of 5-period TEMA returned from TA-Lib is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/z5A2a8Df)

Other values are:
Input array length: 161,
Returned from TA-Lib begin value: 12,
Returned from TA-Lib length value: 150,
Lookback: 12

Comment: My conclusions:
1. Values greater than 1.3285 were not found in resulted array. So resulted data didn't contain values of last bars. Any shifts of resulted array will not be helpful.
2. I use 5-period TEMA (so it's lookback is 12 bars) and I have input array with 161 bars count. So bars are quite enough.